# Git branching strategy for small frequent features targeting single environment

Tags: git, branch, branching-strategy

Our development process is similar to the one described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537723/git-working-strategy-many-features-very-frequent-releases) and requires creation of many small features. Usually 4-8 features per day. All features should be deployed to the same test environment, so there should be single `test` branch.

Which branching strategy should we adopt? Creating separate feature branches seems like a big overhead, at the same time trunk-based development lacks flexibility. Is it OK to mix those approaches (direct commit to `test` for small features and separate branches for relatively big features).

We are totally new to Git and common branching strategies (like git-flow), and trying to find strategy that fits best for small frequent features.

We will be very grateful for any help or pointing in the right direction, since there are not a lot of articles describing branching for small features. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you have at least two main branches:

1. `production` or the `master` branch, the one to be published
2. `test` or the working branch, where you test all new features

Considering your approach to develop all the new features directly on `test` and then merge those new features to `production` (merging `test` to `production`). In some point you will have features that you developed that you don’t want to publish to `production`. Then you will be forced to `reset` your `test` branch to keep working on it or you will end with many unwanted features published to `production`. Or you will need to discard the `test` branch and branch again from `production` to have a clean copy to work on. Then if many team members are working on the `test` branch and all merge their changes to `test`, it will be hard for each team member to track the features that other team members are working on, so the conflict resolution will become harder to accomplish.

I think the best option will be to treat each feature as a different branch, branched directly from `production`. So, for example in a day you want 3 new features, you will branch from `production` and create: `features/one`, `features/two` and `features/three`. When each of those features are ready (at a different time, by different team members) they’re all merged to `test` (each team member will need to be aware only of the changes he made for conflict resolution because he works on a controlled branch with inly the changes that he made to the project ) and then showcased to a client or the team leader. Maybe all the features are approved, but maybe one of those features gets rejected. With this branching strategy it’s very easy now to discard all unwanted features and publish the approved ones: you just need to merge the approved features and discard the others.

Working on different branches for the different features will give you a more granular control of your project, where you work each feature separated and they don’t ever get mixed.

In your case maybe you do small fixes to the project (maybe the project is a website and you just fix typos), you could then have a `hotfix/quick-fixes` branch (branched from `production`) where you work all those small changes (that will be published for surely) and then merge those changes to `test` to make a quick review of those changes or you merge directly to `production` for publishing.

Hope this point of view help you solve your branching strategy.